# When using rails/activerecord to talk to a MySQL database, can I set max_allowed_packet?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

MySQL has a [setting called 'max_allowed_packet'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html) which is set separately for clients and servers.  On the server side it's in a config file, is it possible to set this to a non-default value on the client side when the client is rails ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documnentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

> On the client side, max_allowed_packet has a default of 1GB.

So, you just have to change it on the server side. Depending what version of MySQL you are using, you can do this *on the fly* on a global basis by running

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16777216
```

or

```
SET max_allowed_packet=16777216
```

where I assumed a 16MB max size. As you noted, you can also set the global variable in your `my.cnf`.

Currently, you cannot change this on a per-session basis.

```
mysql> SET SESSION max_allowed_packet=102400000; 

ERROR 1621 (HY000): SESSION variable 'max_allowed_packet' is read-only. Use SET GLOBAL to assign the value
```

Comment: the default is 1MB not 1GB

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if could help , but you can set mysql variable at runtime .

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;")
```